# Select row by user_id and any row which share that entry's event_id

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, json

I have a table which includes the following format:

```
 _______________________________
| event_id | user_id | username |
|-------------------------------|
|    30    |    1    |   user1  |
|    30    |    2    |   user2  |
|    30    |    3    |   user3  |
|    31    |    1    |   user1  |
|    31    |    4    |   user4  |
|    31    |    7    |   user5  |
|    32    |    3    |   user1  |
|    32    |    4    |   user4  |
|    32    |    5    |   user5  |
|_______________________________|
```

I considered storing users as JSON:

```
 _______________________________________________________
| event_id |                   users                    |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|    30    | [{"user_id": 1, "username": "user1"}, ...] |
|    31    | [{"user_id": 1, "username": "user1"}, ...] |
|    32    | [{"user_id": 5, "username": "user5"}, ...] |
|_______________________________________________________|
```

But I imagine this would be awful on performance when trying to look up an event based on a JSON value.

I want to be able to look up any events where a `username` appears, and return all rows which have the same `event_id`.  Is this possible to do in a single query (as I wish to minimize server strain), or should I just do a nested select?

Comment: A join will suffice

Comment: selecting isn't that complicated, it needs only another code, but if you need updating it gets much more complicated. so if you really don't need json don't use it

Comment: Edit your question and show the query used to generate your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to just do a nested select that returns event_id; I initially did not do this as I thought the multiple statement queries option of node-mysql needed to be enabled for it, but it turns out that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to look up any events where a username appears, and return all rows which have the same event_id.

You could use `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.event_id = t.event_id and t1.username = ?
)
```

For performance, you want an index on `(username, event_id)`.

The question mark represents with the `username` that you are looking for.

I would not recommend storing your data as JSON: this would make queries more complicated, for little or no value added (the structure that you are storing is consistent across rows, so it fits very well in a table).

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it a couple different ways based on your suggestion and could still only get it to return the row that matches `username`.  I just decided to do a nested select that returns `event_id`; I initially did not do this as I thought the multiple statement queries option of node-mysql needed to be enabled for it, but it turns out that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using `group_concat`, here is the **[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ds9Cw9k68FdQaQCotsQ5To/4)**.

```
select
    event_id,
    concat('[', group_concat(concat('{"user_id":', user_id, ', "username":"',username,'"}')), ']') as users   
from yourTable
group by
    event_id
```

Output:

```
| event_id | users                                                                                                       |
| -------- | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 30       | [{"user_id":1, "username":"user1"},{"user_id":2, "username":"user2"},{"user_id":3, "username":"user3"}] |
| 31       | [{"user_id":1, "username":"user1"},{"user_id":4, "username":"user4"},{"user_id":7, "username":"user5"}] |
| 32       | [{"user_id":3, "username":"user1"},{"user_id":4, "username":"user4"},{"user_id":5, "username":"user5"}] |
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that a query is used to generate your table.  If so, I think you want something like this:

```
select e.*, u.user_name
from events e join 
     users u
     on e.user_id = u.user_id
where exists (select 1
              from events e2
              where e2.event_id = e.event_id and
                    e2.user_id = :user_id  -- whichever one you want
             );
```

If this is consistent with your query, then an index on `events(event_id, user_id)` would help performance.